# Android ListView with ListAdapter, need to always have a selected entry

Tags: android, listview, highlight, listadapter, selected

i have a ListView (lvProperties) whose adapter is a custom ListAdapter (not an ArrayAdapter). This adapter gets is data from an Instance variable of custom type Section (containing a few Strings, Integers, ArrayLists and methods).

I need this list to ALWAYS display a selection (there must be always a selected element, even on activity launch).

When using a simple ArrayAdapter in the past something like this would be enough:

```
lvProperties.requestFocus();
lvProperties.setSelection(0);
```

However, in this case it does not work at all. I have been looking around SO and the web and used:

```
lvProperties.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
lvProperties.setFocusable(true);            
lvProperties.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
lvProperties.requestFocus();
lvProperties.setSelection(0);
```

And still nothing.

My ListAdapter:

```
    lvProperties.setAdapter(new ListAdapter() {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v=convertView;

                if(v==null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v=vi.inflate(R.layout.detail_row1, null);
                }

                TextView name=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.propName);
                TextView value=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.propValue);

                if(name!=null) {
                    name.setText(section.propNames.get(position));
                }
                if(value!=null) {
                value.setText(section.propValues.get(position));
                }

                return v;
            }

        @Override
        public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {}

        @Override
        public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {}

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return section.propNames.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

My unimplemented OnItemSelectedListener:

```
    lvProperties.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

And my detail_row1.xml (I will be implementing to layouts for the rows next, but this is how it's right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="6dip"
  >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/propName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:layout_weight="1"    
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:paddingTop="10sp"
    android:paddingBottom="10sp"
    android:paddingLeft="4sp"
     />

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:id="@+id/propValue"       
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingTop="10sp"
    android:paddingBottom="10sp"
    android:paddingRight="4sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    />  

</LinearLayout><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="6dip"
  >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/propName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:layout_weight="1"    
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:paddingTop="10sp"
    android:paddingBottom="10sp"
    android:paddingLeft="4sp"
    />

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:id="@+id/propValue"       
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingTop="10sp"
    android:paddingBottom="10sp"
    android:paddingRight="4sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    />  

</LinearLayout>
```

any help / pointer to guide on how to accomplish this? I don't want to use a drawable, just the default selector for the Theme I'm using.

Again, there must always be one selected entry in the list.

I realize that by design this is not the intended behavior for lists BUT this is one of those cases where one size doesn't fit all

Comment: "I need this list to ALWAYS display a selection" -- selection is only to be shown via the arrow keys, D-pad, or other non-touchscreen pointing device. "I realize that by design this is not the intended behavior for lists BUT this is one of those cases where one size doesn't fit all" -- if you would care to explain why, perhaps we can figure out some other means of indicating whatever it is you want to let users know about. For example, "activated" is a state used on HC/ICS/JB for indicating the context of some adjacent material chosen via the list.

Comment: the reason why, briefly, is that other elements within the activity get populated based on what is selected on the list. I'm porting one of my apps from iOS to Android and want to reproduce this (from that app) http://bit.ly/NIXRkZ. I know they are different platforms but that's how I'd like to be.

Comment: What you are describing is "activated", but as a concept that only exists on Android 3.0+, and therefore will only be expected by users on such devices. And even on those devices, "activated" only occurs after the user taps, not before.

Comment: Well, this app I tried to port once back in the days of Froyo. At the time the main activity (in this case this would be the detail activity) had a ListView with an ArrayAdapter and a simple listView.requestFocus() / listView.setSelection() would do the job. I never completed that porting at the time as I didn't know Java and thought it was not worth the effort. i just don't see how if I was able to emulate that before I can't do it now

Comment: You might try extending `BaseAdapter` rather than rolling a pure `ListAdapter` straight from the interface, and see if that helps. I have no idea why the type of adapter would affect anything. The definition of the *layout* can be important, if something in there changes/interferes with the selection highlight, but it should not matter whether the adapter is an `ArrayAdapter`, `CursorAdapter`, or a `BaleOfHayAdapter`.

Comment: Hi Commons. thanks for the help and interest on this question. I'm trying 'emulating' the selections based on <selector>s right now, if that doesnt work I will take a look at BaseAdapter as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all others interested, I just replicated what I needed with having to mess with ChoiceMode, requestFocus, setSelection, etc etc etc, works fine in API 8 upwards

when app launches I want the first row to be highlighted already:

selectedItem.setValue(0) // an inner class i have, could be a simple integer as well

my Inner Class ArrayDapter (I need it to see the parent selectedItem all the time):

note: i will be changed the hard coded color next, i just solved the problem i had:

```
public class DetailsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Section> {

    public Section section;
    public View v;
    public Context c;

    public DetailsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            Section s) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);

        this.section=s;

        this.c=context;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return section.propNames.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        this.v = convertView;

        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(v==null) {     
            v=vi.inflate(R.layout.detail_row1, null); 
        }

        **LinearLayout llc=(LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.detail_container);**
        TextView name=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.propName);
        TextView value=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.propValue);
        if(pos==selectedItem.value) {
           llc.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        } else
        { llc.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);}
        Log.e("Pos",""+pos);

        if(llc!=null) {

        }

        if(name!=null) {

            name.setText(section.namesAsArray()[pos]);
        }
        if(value!=null) {
            value.setText(section.valuesAsArray()[pos]);
        }


        return v;

    }
}
```

The trick so I could avoid android:state_xxxxxxx in my XML file was to wrap my custom row with a nested LinearLayout filling the outer one.

the layout for the row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/detail_linearLayout"
>

<LinearLayout 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_weight="0"
   android:id="@+id/detail_container"
     android:padding="6dip"
   >

<TextView 
android:id="@+id/propName"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
android:layout_weight="1"    
android:textSize="16sp"
android:textStyle="bold" 
android:textColor="#000000"
android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
android:paddingTop="10sp"
android:paddingBottom="10sp"
android:paddingLeft="4sp"
/>

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:id="@+id/propValue"       
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:paddingTop="10sp"
android:paddingBottom="10sp"
android:paddingRight="4sp"
android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
/>  

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

finally, on I set my OnItemClickListener:

```
    lvProperties.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

                **selectedItem.value=arg2;
                lvProperties.invalidateViews();**
                        .
                                    .
                                    .
                     }});
```

done and done!